# Code implementation for openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, openmp, implementation

I want to implement following sequential code  in OpenMP (2 core) for parallel computing.

Which modifications should I do to run it with OpenMP? If you help me I will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
      program POTENTIAL
      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)
      data rl2,rl2allow /1.,1.E-7/
c..Read the input data, generate the grid data and initialize the solution

      call INIT 

c..Start the iterative solution loop 

      k = 0
      DO WHILE (k .lt. kmax .and. rl2 .gt. rl2allow)
         k = k + 1
         call BC
c..Point iterative solutions

         call SOR
c..Line iterative solution

c        call SLOR
c..Update phi_k array and evaluate the residual

         rl2=0.
         do j = 2,jmax-1
         do i = 2,imax-1
           rl2 = rl2 + (phi_kp1(i,j) - phi_k(i,j))**2
           phi_k(i,j)  = phi_kp1(i,j)
         enddo
         enddo
         rl2 = SQRT(rl2/((imax-2)*(jmax-2)))
         print*, 'Residual@k=',k,rl2
c..Output intermediate solutions

         if( mod(k,kout).eq.0 .and. k.ne.kmax) call IO(k)
      ENDDO
      call IO(k)

      stop
      end     

      subroutine SOR

      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)

      beta2 = (dr/dth)**2
c..Solve for phi^k+1

      do i = 2,imax-1
      c1 = beta2/r(i)**2
      c2 = 0.5*dr/r(i)
      c3 = 0.5/(1.+c1)
      do j = 2,jmax-1
c..Implement the point Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel and SOR methods

      phi_kp1(i,j) = c3*((1.-c2)*phi_k(i-1,j) + (1.+c2)*phi_k(i+1,j)
     >                     + c1*(phi_k(i,j-1) + phi_k(i,j+1)) )
      enddo
      enddo
      return 
      end



      subroutine  INIT
      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)
      data r1,r2/1.0,5.0/, imax,jmax/101,91/

c..Read input parameters like imax, jmax

      print*, 'Enter kmax and kout :'
      read(*,*) kmax, kout

      pi  = 4.*ATAN(1.)
      dr  = (r2-r1)/float(imax-1)
      dth = pi/float(jmax-1)
c..Grid generation 

      do j=1,jmax
      do i=1,imax
         r(i)   = r1 + dr*(i-1) 
         th(j)  = dth*(j-1) 
         x(i,j) = r(i)*COS(th(j))
         y(i,j) = r(i)*SIN(th(j))
c...initialize the phi arrays

         phi_k(i,j)   = r(i)*COS(th(j))
         phi_kp1(i,j) = 0.
      enddo
      enddo
      call BC
      call IO(1)

      return 
      end

c-------------------------------------------------------------------

      subroutine BC
      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)

      do i = 1,imax
         phi_k(i,1)      = phi_k(i,2)
         phi_kp1(i,1)    = phi_k(i,2)
         phi_k(i,jmax)   = phi_k(i,jmax-1)
         phi_kp1(i,jmax) = phi_k(i,jmax-1)
      enddo
      do j = 1,jmax
         phi_k(1,j)      = phi_k(2,j)
         phi_kp1(1,j)    = phi_k(2,j) 
         phi_k(imax,j)   = r(imax)*COS(th(j))
         phi_kp1(imax,j) = phi_k(imax,j)
      enddo

      return 
      end

c-------------------------------------------------------------------

      subroutine VELOCITY(vx,vy)
      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)
      dimension vx(imx,jmx),vy(imx,jmx)
      do j = 1,jmax
      do i = 1,imax
         if(i .eq. 1) then
           vr = (phi_k(2,j)-phi_k(1,j))/dr
         elseif(i .eq. imax) then
           vr = (phi_k(imax,j)-phi_k(imax-1,j))/dr
         else
           vr = 0.5*(phi_k(i+1,j)-phi_k(i-1,j))/dr
         endif
         if(j .eq. 1) then
           vth = (phi_k(i,2)-phi_k(i,1))/(dth*r(i))
         elseif(j .eq. jmax) then
           vth = (phi_k(i,jmax)-phi_k(i,jmax-1))/(dth*r(i))
         else
           vth = 0.5*(phi_k(i,j+1)-phi_k(i,j-1))/(dth*r(i))
         endif
         vx(i,j) = vr*COS(th(j)) - vth*SIN(th(j))
         vy(i,j) = vr*SIN(th(j)) + vth*COS(th(j))
      enddo
      enddo
      return 
      end

c-------------------------------------------------------------------

      subroutine  IO(k)
c..Output solution in tecplot format

      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)
      dimension vx(imx,jmx),vy(imx,jmx)
      character fname*32,string*8,ext*5

      call VELOCITY(vx,vy)
      write(string,'(f8.5)') float(k)/100000
      read(string,'(3x,a5)') ext
      fname = 'vars-'//ext//'.tec' 
      open(1,file=fname,form='formatted')
      write(1,*) ' variables="x","y","phi","u","v" '
      write(1,*) ' zone i=',imax, ', j=',jmax
      do j = 1,jmax
      do i = 1,imax
         write(1,*) x(i,j),y(i,j),phi_k(i,j),vx(i,j),vy(i,j)
      enddo
      enddo
      close(1)

      return
      end

c-------------------------------------------------------------------
      SUBROUTINE THOMAS(mx,il,iu,A,B,C,R)
c............................................................
c Solution of a tridiagonal system of n equations of the form
c  A(i)*x(i-1) + B(i)*x(i) + C(i)*x(i+1) = R(i)  for i=il,iu
c  the solution X(i) is stored in F(i)
c  A(il-1) and C(iu+1) are not used.
c  A,B,C,R are arrays to be provided by the user
c............................................................

      dimension  a(mx),b(mx),c(mx),r(mx),x(mx)
      x(il)=c(il)/b(il)
      r(il)=r(il)/b(il)
      do i=il+1,iu
         z=1./(b(i)-a(i)*x(i-1))
         x(i)=c(i)*z
         r(i)=(r(i)-a(i)*r(i-1))*z
      enddo
      do i=iu-1,il,-1
         r(i)=r(i)-x(i)*r(i+1)
      enddo
      return
      end
```

Comment: I have the feeling I've seen [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34912742/5239503) before...

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the iterative part of your code (lines 14-37) we observe that there are two invocations (BC and SOR) that execute code in loops. These are potential places where to put OpenMP directives. In both routines, the loops do not expose data dependencies that prevent the execution in parallel so you could apply the following transformations.

For the BC routine (below) you can use two times !$OMP PARALLEL DO to distribute the work of the two loops (one directive for each loop) among the available threads.

```
      subroutine BC                                                                                  
      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)                                                                   
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout                                                              
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)                                      
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)                                                  

!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(IMAX,PHI_K,PHI_KP1)                                                         
      do i = 1,imax                                                                                  
         phi_k(i,1)      = phi_k(i,2)                                                                
         phi_kp1(i,1)    = phi_k(i,2)                                                                
         phi_k(i,jmax)   = phi_k(i,jmax-1)                                                           
         phi_kp1(i,jmax) = phi_k(i,jmax-1)                                                           
      enddo                                                                                          
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO                                                                                

!$OMP PARALLEL DO SHARED(JMAX,PHI_K,PHI_KP1)                                                         
      do j = 1,jmax                                                                                  
         phi_k(1,j)      = phi_k(2,j)                                                                
         phi_kp1(1,j)    = phi_k(2,j)                                                                
         phi_k(imax,j)   = r(imax)*COS(th(j))                                                        
         phi_kp1(imax,j) = phi_k(imax,j)                                                             
      enddo                                                                                          
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO                                                                                

      return                                                                                         
      end
```

and similarly for SOR, you can distribute the work of the outer loop among threads. In this case, each thread will require a private copy of the temporal variables (c1, c2, c3) and the iterative variable (j).

```
      subroutine SOR                                                                                 

      parameter (imx=201, jmx=201)                                                                   
      common /pars/ imax,jmax,kmax,kout                                                              
      common /grid/ dr,dth,r(imx),th(jmx),x(imx,jmx),y(imx,jmx)                                      
      common /vars/ phi_k(imx,jmx),phi_kp1(imx,jmx)                                                  

      beta2 = (dr/dth)**2                                                                            
c..Solve for phi^k+1                                                                                 

C$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(c1,c2,c3,j) SHARED(IMAX,JMAX,PHI_KP1,PHI_K)                                
      do i = 2,imax-1                                                                                
      c1 = beta2/r(i)**2                                                                             
      c2 = 0.5*dr/r(i)                                                                               
      c3 = 0.5/(1.+c1)                                                                               
      do j = 2,jmax-1                                                                                
c..Implement the point Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel and SOR methods                                          

      phi_kp1(i,j) = c3*((1.-c2)*phi_k(i-1,j) + (1.+c2)*phi_k(i+1,j)                                 
     >                     + c1*(phi_k(i,j-1) + phi_k(i,j+1)) )                                      
      enddo                                                                                          
      enddo                                                                                          
C$OMP END PARALLEL DO                                                                                

      return                                                                                         
      end
```

You may want to explore the rest of your code and see for further parallelization opportunities. You may use a profiler (gprof, TAU, Vampir, Paraver) to identify the application hotspots and focus the parallelization there.